# How to run liveness probe as non-root user?

Tags: kubernetes

I noticed that my liveness probes ( for example from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/probe/http-liveness.yaml)) runs as a **root** user. I could use "su -c" to change the user "inside" the probe CLI, but may be there is a way to declare liveness to run the probe as non-root ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 3):

Check out kubernetes docs for Security Context: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

You can define a securityContext key under spec or spec.containers[].

Allowed values can be found in the API docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo-2
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-demo-2
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 2000
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```